# Stop retrying periodic celery task on error

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

Imagine a task in `celery schedule`, that runs each minute and **sends email** on errors. If there is an error, it's more often persistent, like database unavailability, so mail box get's spammed with similar emails.

What's the possible workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a flag so the program knows whether it has already sent an alarm email, which gets set back to False once the database comes back online

The code is just an example of the concept.. it's unrelated to Celery, however I'm sure you can work it to fit your needs

```
database_flag = False

database = get_database()

while True:
    if not database.is_faulted():
        database_flag = False
    elif database.is_faulted() and not database_flag:
        send_email()
        database_flag = True

    time.sleep(60)
```